# Unity3d C# - How to check if a button has been pressed, and then instantiate an object

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

So for the past two days (no joke) I have been trying to figure out how to check if a button is pressed, and then if so, make it instantiate an object. I have tried multiple methods so far and maybe one of those methods were closer to getting where I wanted but for now I will just show what I have currently. Right now, the problem is me detecting if the button has even been clicked in the first place.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Master : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button storeButton;
    public Transform hands;
    public GameObject gun1;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        gun1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Weapon1");
        hands = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        // storeButton.onClick.AddListener(MyFunction);//adds a listener for when you click the button
        storeButton.onClick.AddListener(() => MyFunction());
    }

    void MyFunction()
    {
        Debug.Log("YOUR PRESSED THE DAMN BUTTON");
        // Instantiate(gun1, hands.position, hands.rotation);
        GameObject.Instantiate(gun1, hands.position, hands.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks right so far. Any error Logs in your Console? Maybe try the Start() Method instead of OnEnable() http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

Comment: There were no errors and my Debug.Log doesn't get sent. Same issue when I tried using Start() :/

Comment: What you can try is to set the Action over the Inspector.

Comment: Do you have an EventSystem in your Scene? Dos the Button plays an Animation when hovering with the Mouse?

Comment: @Marcel I did not at the time! Its working now! Thanks!

Comment: Okay nice. I will write an answer in a minute.

Comment: @Sl0thzy please accept my Answer, It helps future users' who have similar problem and are looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an **EventSystem** to your Scene.

Otherwise you cant click Buttons an other Stuff.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html